# Сокеты. Есть ли разница между socket_write() и socket_send()?

Tags: php, сокет

Существует ли принципиальная разница между PHP-функцией [socket_write()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-write.php) и [socket_send()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-send.php)? Если да, то когда какую из них использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Да, разница есть.
Функция socket_write() записывает в socket записывает данные из указанного буфера data,
а функция socket_send() отправляет длину байт в socket

Comment: *"отправляет длину байт в socket"* --- ну нет же)  то, что в доках написано *"отправляет length байт"* не читается как *"отправляет длину байт"*....а читается как *"отправляет байты в количестве length"*

Answer (score 0):

Это действительно интересно, в чём разница :-)

Но я нашёл на просторах интернета, что утверждается, следующее:

> socket_send() This function sends data to the connected socket
>
> socket_write() write data to the socket cache

То есть получается, если основываться на этих данных, что socket_send шлёт данные в сокет, а socket_write записывает в кэш этого соединения (сокета) данные.

Comment: Насколько можно верить интернету? По хорошему, надо взять сорсы ПХП и посмтореть,  какие системные вызовы (функции libc) исполняются в первом и втором случаях